# banana at party

Tags: logical-deduction

At a party, three boys ate bananas.

> - First boy: I ate more than second one and he ate more than third one
> - Second boy: Third one ate more than second one and me
> - Third boy: I ate the same numbers of bananas as the first one. And second boy ate more than us

If you know that between two boys, the one who ate less says more true statements, which one of these statements can't be true?

1. third one ate more than two other boys
2. second boy ate more than two other boys
3. first one ate more than second one
4. second one ate more than first one
5. second one ate more than third one
6. third one ate more than second one
7. third one ate more than first one
8. first one ate more than third one
9. all three boys ate the same numbers of bananas.

Comment: Is this a puzzle of your own devising, or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: it comes from somewhere else

Comment: Then you'll need to tell us where: we try to be super-careful about anything resembling plagiarism here. If it's something you can link to, link to it; if not, give as much information as you can about where it comes from. Thanks!

Comment: it is an famous puzzle in Persian language  and i just translated to English. no links are available.

Comment: You said: Third boy: I ate the same numbers of bananas and second one ate more than us.

Did you mean: Third boy: I ate the same numbers of bananas as the second boy. One ate more than us.